# What's a succinct, useful and efficient way to store large time-series in F#?

Tags: f#, finance, time-series

I'm currently learning F# and I'm exploring using it to analyse financial time-series. Can anyone recommend a good data structure to store time-series data in?

F# offers a rich selection of native types and I'm looking for a some simple combination that would provide an elegant, succinct and efficient solution.

I'm looking store tick data, which consists of millions of records each with a time stamp, and several (~5-20) fields of numerical and textual data, with possible missing values.

My first thoughts are perhaps a sequence of tuples or records, but I was wondering if someone could kindly suggest something that has worked well in the real world.

EDIT:

A few extra points for clarification:

The common operations that I'm likely to require are:

- Time based lookup - i.e. find the most recent data point at a given time
- Time based joins
- Appends
  (Updates and deletes are going to be rare. )

I should make it clear I'm exploring using F# primarily as an interactive tool for research, with the ability to compile as a (really big) added bonus.

ANOTHER EDIT:

I should also have mentioned, my role/use of F# and this data is purely within research not development. The intention being that once we understand the data (and what we want to do with it) better then we can later specify tools that our developers would build. Such as data warehouses etc. at which we'd start using their data structures etc.

Although, I am concerned that our models are computationally intensive, use a lot of memory and can't always be coded in a recursive manner. So we many end up having to query out large chunks anyway.

I should also say that I've always used Matlab or R for these sorts of tasks before but I'm now interested in F# as it offers that interactive, high level flexibility for Research but the same code can be used in production.

My apologies for not giving this context information at the start (It's my first question), I can see now that it helps people form their answers.

My thanks again to everyone that's taken the time to help me.

Comment: I'm not very sure, but ... Do you really need to load millions of records for time-series analysis? As far as I know, data-mining models can be built from randomly sampled data and tested on other randomly sampled data. (Unless you have strict requirement to build model from all database rows)

Comment: I included the millions to give some scale to the problem. Sure, that many records would often not need to be loaded for many applications and in others there would be a trade off between convenience, load efficiency and memory used etc. Sub-sampling, moving windows etc. could be used. But there are cases where a whole big pile of ticks would be convenient - for example if I was experimenting with the affects of aggregating data over a wide range of timescales.

Comment: That may also mean, that you should at first aggregate data into some database storage. (Usually such aggregation is done into data warehouses). And after that - you can do data-mining from already aggregated (efficient/small) data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best choice of data structure depends upon what operations you want to do on it.

The simplest would be an array of structs. This has the advantages of fast random lookup, good space efficiency for an uncompressed representation and good locality. If there is sharing between substructures (like the strings) then intern them to make sure they get shared.

Alternatives might be a `seq` that is loaded from disk on-demand, a singly-linked list that allows you to prepend elements quickly or a balanced binary trees that allows operations like insertion at random locations efficiently.

Comment: Thanks Jon, that's several good suggestions to try out. I have a few questions if you don't mind: For the first two suggestions how would I access based on a time point? I'm not sure what you mean by 'intern' the strings? (sorry I've been using Matlab for the last 10 years) and which would fit best with the elegant functional nature of F#? - e.g. I like the ideas of the on-demand seq

Comment: Provided the elements of the array are sorted by time, you can find them in O(*log n*) using binary search. A `seq` or `list` would require linear search. Balanced binary search trees with the time as key are also O(*log n*). Read up on *hash consing* and `System.String.Intern` on .NET (it means reuse structurally equal values).

Comment: BTW, `Map` in F# provides a balanced binary tree that associates keys with values (i.e. a dictionary) but you'll need to know the exact time (key) to find the associated value. If you built your own balanced search tree then you would be able find values over ranges of times efficiently as well but, as I said, it all depends upon what you need to do efficiently with your data.

Answer (score 4):

It really sounds like your data should be stored and queried in a relational database (where is it currently stored?: loading millions of records with several fields into memory must be an expensive operation, and could leave you with stale data and difficulty persisting changes). And then you could use the F# LINQ to SQL implementation (which I believe you can find in the Power Pack) to have F# expressions translated to SQL expressions.

Here's a link from Don Syme about LINQ Support in F# Power Pack: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2009/10/23/a-quick-refresh-on-query-support-in-the-f-power-pack.aspx

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I will look into that. It's certainly our plan to move this data into a database. But as a researcher, I have to do some experimentation to understand the data and how we will use it in order to specify how the db is set up. One concern I need to look into is; we do a lot of computation with this data, for example to maintain multiple adaptive models over various time frames. Not all of which can be coded in a recursive manner. As the db is probably not the best place for this computation we may have to query big chunks anyway.

Comment: Relational DBs are a waste of time if your data is over real size...ie tick data. If you want to use a db use a column based store with time series operators.

Comment: @Steve, I believe you. I said relational simply because that is what I am familiar with, and since F# comes with a LINQ to SQL implementation. Maybe it would help the OP if you named an implementation of the kind of database you describe (at least I would be interested).

Comment: Two commercial ones are kdb from kx systems and i believe sybase rap also implements this.