# How do I do an efficient temporal join of records in an array?

Tags: f#

I would like to join a record to the next record at least X days/minutes/seconds into the future. I need to do this with arrays with a few hundred thousand records. I am open to sequences/lists/arrays but I believe arrays are likely to be fastest.

I can do this quickly in Deedle with `Frame.joinAlign JoinKind.Left Lookup.ExactOrGreater`, but I have an easier time reasoning about transformations using standard arrays/sequences/lists.

The following example is fine with 1000 records but very slow when 100k. A comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386242/whats-a-succinct-useful-and-efficient-way-to-store-large-time-series-in-f) suggests a binary search but I do not see how to do that here where the search is based on an inequality.

```
type Test1 = {
    Date : DateTime
    Value : float
}

type Test2 = {
    Date1 :DateTime
    Value1 : float
    Date2 : DateTime
    Value2 : float
}

let rng = System.Random()
let rng2 = System.Random()
let rs = 
[| for i = 1 to 1000 do 
    let baseDay = DateTime(2016,1,1).AddDays(float i)
    let actualDay = baseDay.AddDays(float (rng2.Next(7))) 
    yield {Date = actualDay; Value = rng.NextDouble() }|]

[| for r in rs do
    let futureDay = r.Date.AddDays(float 4)
    let r2 =
        rs
        |> Array.filter (fun x -> x.Date > futureDay)
        |> Array.tryHead
    let nr =
        match r2 with
        | Some x -> Some {Date1 = r.Date;Value1 = r.Value; Date2=x.Date;Value2 = x.Value}
        | None -> None
    if nr.IsSome then yield nr.Value |]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this expression:

```
let r2 =
    rs
    |> Array.filter (fun x -> x.Date > futureDay)
    |> Array.tryHead
```

This filters the *entire* array and creates a new array with *all* the matching items, when you really just want the first matching item. And this is happening for *every `r`*. Try this instead:

```
let r2 = rs |> Array.tryFind (fun x -> x.Date > futureDay)
```

N.b. your logic would have been fine if you were dealing with sequences rather than arrays as the filter would have been evaluated lazily, but of course sequences are going to be slower than arrays in general. The thing to keep in mind is that whereas the `Seq` module is lazy (with some exceptions), when using the `Array` and `List` (and `Set` and `Map`, etc.) modules, every step in the chain/pipeline will eagerly allocate a new `list`/`array` and consequently can be very expensive when working with large collections.

If sorting `rs` doesn't affect your logic or expected output, a further improvement can be made by using [`Array.FindIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhdxx3we.aspx) to start searching at `r`'s index rather than from the beginning of the array each time:

```
Array.sortInPlace rs
rs
|> Seq.mapi (fun i r ->
    let futureDay = r.Date.AddDays 4.0
    let r2Index = Array.FindIndex (rs, i, (fun x -> x.Date > futureDay))
    match r2Index with
      | -1 -> None
      | i' -> let x = rs.[i']
              Some { Date1=r.Date; Value1=r.Value; Date2=x.Date; Value2=x.Value })
|> Seq.choose id
|> Array.ofSeq
```

This should offer a **significant** improvement over even the `Array.tryFind` approach as only a handful of array elements will need to be scanned each time.

Here are FSI timings from my ageing tablet with the system under otherwise nil load:

- 10k elements:

  - unsorted + `Array.filter` (original code): 00:00:08.783
  - unsorted + `Array.tryFind`: 00:00:03.844
  - `Array.sort` + `Seq.mapi`: 00:00:00.027
- 100k elements:

  - unsorted + `Array.filter`: I didn't bother.
  - unsorted + `Array.tryFind`: 00:06:14.288
  - `Array.sort` + `Seq.mapi`: 00:00:00.305

Comment: @nh2 : As I said, `Array.mapi` will create a new array the same size as `rs`. However you don't actually ever want that array, you just want the element indices. `Seq.mapi` is lazy, so by piping the intermediate steps through the `Seq` module instead of the `Array`, the only new array getting created is the actual result. You could use `Array.mapi` and `Array.choose` instead, and that may well turn out to be faster due to avoiding `seq` overhead, but you'll need to profile to see whether the extra allocations are worth it.

Comment: Does the Array.FindIndex call above assume that rs was sorted in place (as it was in a prior version of the answer)? The question gives a sorted rs, but the answer is intended to work with an rs that is not sorted. The current answer looks like it is searching for an index in rs ordered as it was before the Array.sort call.

Comment: @nh2 : Apologies, you're quite correct that `rs` itself does need to be sorted for my answer (or a separate sorted array could be used). However, the question does _not_ give a sorted `rs`; it would without `.AddDays(float (rng2.Next(7)))`, but as-is, it's only _nearly_ sorted.

Comment: Ha, yes true about my rs not being sorted as I thought. Anyway, great answer that I will use all the time. Much appreciated.